# Synchronous http post angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have a login component where the user inputs it's e-mail and password. The component sends the fields to the service, where i make a http post request to my nodejs backend to know if the user exists and if password is correct.

The problem is that the response from the server is undefined, but I can get the value of the response from the network of chrome.

I believe the problem is that the request is asynchronous, and so it returns the response before it actually gets the response.

After searching I couldn't find very useful information on how to make the request synchronous.

Here are the codes of my component and of service!

In my component:

```
login_function(){
    this.token = this.global.check_login(this.login_user,this.login_pass)
        .subscribe(data => this.postData = JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(this.token);}
}
```

In the service:

```
check_login(user, pass) {
    let data = {user:user,password:pass};
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method:'post' });

    console.log("user:"+user+"\npass:"+pass);

    return this.http.post(url, {username:user,password:pass}, options)
        .map((response:Response)=> response.json());
  }
```

Comment: check_login is asyncronous, so this.token is undefined. check login is returning an **observable**, so you should **subscribe** to the check_login function and assign the value to `this.token` when the data is available. You are mixing syncronous tasks with asyncronous tasks, which is why `this.token` is undefined when you log it. The solution is NOT to make the requests syncronous, but to (properly) subscribe to the observable, syncronous http requests are not that recommended. Also, url is undefined unless declared somewhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You should be aware that using synchronous ajax calls is a deprecated as it leads to a bad user experience since *it will freeze the window until it completes*.

Comment: @megamit as it is a login page, and in order to allow access to the user to the rest of the application I need to login him

Comment: @LuísCosta - read the marked duplicate. This will give you a solid foundation for working with asynchronous calls in typescript and javascript. You must understand this fundamental concept and how to program using callbacks and promises if you want to write any type of javascript / typescript code that interacts with a server/service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rightly thinking that it is due to async execution of statements. Change your component code to:

```
login_function() {
    this.global.check_login(this.login_user, this.login_pass).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
 }
```

Service should be updated to the following code:
(Assuming that your server accepts 'user' and 'password' as keys)

```
check_login(user,pass){
    console.log("user:"+user+"\npass:"+pass);

    let bodyString = JSON.stringify({user:user,password:pass});
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); // ... Set content type to JSON
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers}); // Create a request option
    return this.http
     .post(url,bodyString,options)
     .map((response:Response)=> response.json() );

}
```

Comment: I assume here that he receives json object as a response

Comment: In the console it prints: {}

Comment: what is 'global' variable. It should be an instance of Service injected in your constructor? i.e. constructor(private global: ServiceName){}

Comment: global is the instance of the service!

import {GlobalService} from 'app/service/global.service';

constructor(private global:GlobalService){}

Comment: and are you using the data variable in the line `let data = {user:user,password:pass};` ?

Comment: I was using that variable at first, but then I wrote the information directly on the request

Comment: I changed the component to `this.global.check_login(this.login_user, this.login_pass).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      });` and it prints: "Object {}" when I open it, it has nothing inside

Comment: in your service you have used 2 different post requests.. Previously you sent {user: .., password: ...} and now {username: .., password: ...}. What exactly does your server expect?

Comment: There is a possibility that your server code may be incorrect

Comment: The server is expecting a username and a password, and it is returning {"login":"OK"}. I could see that as I saved the request response (in the service) and asked for it later, and I could see it, the problem is that I want the service to communicate with the componnent only when it has the response

Comment: `console.log(data);` inside subscribe prints only when it has received the response from the service

Comment: `console.log(data)` prints `Object {}` but when I go to network and open the field response I get `{"login":"OK"}`

Comment: this kinda not working for me . can you help me?? @JainamJhaveri